# grep returning undefined when trying to access object in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array have built up with a series of objects in it, but when i am trying to use grep to bring back just one object based on a condition, it is always returning undefined

Array is like

```
[Object { Id=61, Name=”A Name”, Department=”A Department”, Tag=”A Tag”}, Object {Id=62....
```

Now the id i am passing in, is not the index, it is the actual Id of the object..ie: 61

```
var resultOut = $.grep(myArray, function (e) {
        return e.Id === id;
    });

console.log(resultOut[0]);
```

Now it has been mentioned that it may be because it is changing the id i am passing in as a string, so the e.Id === id does not match, ut i have no way of checking this

Comment: Have you tried with == operator? Because === checks for the type also. Is type your id integer?

Answer (score 0):

If it's `id` being a string, two ways to fix it. Use `==`:

```
return e.Id == id;
```

Or convert `id` to int:

```
return e.Id === +id;
//              ^
```

The `+` before `id` is equivalent to a `parseInt()`.

Comment: i have tried it with == and am still getting no results back..how infuriating

Comment: Try `console.log(id)` and `console.log(e.Id)` in your function, to be sure `id` is good and to see if there are objects matching it.

Comment: i figured this out not so long back, i was actually returning an array within an array but it was not showing like this on my console.logs